# VMware Host IP Address

Tags: vmware, virtualhost, vsphere, hypervisor

Is there any possibility to get the VMware Host IP address using VIJava API? I'll get Entity Name and DNS name through this API but in some environment these names are not valid so, I'm unable to get the IP address. If API itself returns IP then it could be fine.

Is there any API call to get the VMware Host IP address?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'host' do you mean the HostSystem or do you mean VirtualMachine when you say 'host'?

Comment: Host means ESX/ESXi host whether it is possible tor retrieve the Host IP address by API? For Virtual Machines we can able to get the IP through API itself (if VMware Tools has been installed) but I don't know about the host.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about what IP you would want, do you use DVS or standard vSwitch, are you looking for vmkernel IP addresses, etc?